eevee alpha image won't reflect
When I have an image with an alpha (such as a tree) it won't reflect in another object when using Eevee, but does with Cycles. Does anyone have a solution for this?
Tree: Principled BSDF with a png tree with alpha. The ground is also a BSDF with the Roughness at 0.
Blender 4.2
Raytracing on


What are your shaders ? Tree and ground

Probably need to add a reflection capture plane or sphere. Then bake the reflections.

Hello and welcome, please add more details about your settings and scene, the more info, the better. Also, make sure to have "Raytraicing" checked under render settings

Please clarify your situation: shader nodes for the tree, render settings, and which Blender version (Eevee was massively updated in v4.2). Additionally, you can also share your file with us.

TNow using 4.2 (was hoping it would work in the update).
